# Raspberry Pi 4 solid red and green light (no matter whats connected)

Tags: pi-4

my Raspberry Pi 4 suddenly stopped working after moving to a new apartment. Both the red and green light are always on (even without an sd card). The pi was only used for some simple home automation stuff and has always been in a case.

I tried reflashing the sd card and another power adapter. Also some other things I found on google where the sd card was involved. But it seems like the pi does not even get access to the sd card...

Is there anything I can do to get it working again?

Comment: try a USB thumb drive

Comment: Have you read the Pi4 boot sticky? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151#p1485558

Comment: @CoderMike My LEDs dont blink at all, even without an sd card. In this post it says that  the EEPROM code is corrupted but I cant find a solution without using an SD card.

Comment: @JaromandaX Do you mean I should reinstall EEPROM with an USB stick instead of an SD card? Would this work the same way as with an SD card?

Comment: More posts: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=250183

Comment: my comment had naff all to do with eeprom issues

Comment: @CoderMike Thank you but I tried everything I found there already. They dont work because they require a functioning sd card

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay, so you mean just using the stick as the boot device? I will try that when I'm home.

Comment: With hdmi connected and no sd card, do you get anything on screen? Is it still under warranty?

Comment: `stopped working after moving to a new apartment` ... did you protect the RPi against damage during the move?

Comment: @CoderMike I can't check that right now because I dont have an HDMI-Adapter. It was running headless only. I don't think it's under warranty. Its around 2 years old.

Comment: @jsotola It has always been in a case like this:
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1560/1473/products/Heatsink_case_3_of_6_1024x1024_8cfcf81c-7f33-4eb7-bb3f-64370aa82182.jpg?v=1573589458

And it was packaged pretty secure. I can't really imagine that the hardware got damaged during the move. Before moving it was out of use for a few months and after moving I wanted to use a freshly setup sd card. I think its more likely that it got broken during the process of trying to get it to run.

Comment: I'm thinking in terms of ESD damage

Comment: On most models inc. the Pi 4, solid green = 1) No SD card inserted, 2) Improperly formatted/invalid/defunct SD card inserted, or 3) Broken SD card reader -- and for the 4: 4) Corrupt/invalid eeprom.

Comment: @JaromandaX Same results with a fresh installed Raspberry OS on an USB stick unfortunately

Comment: @jsotola Unlikely I would say. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: @goldilocks I just tried to boot it with an USB device, still no success. So I think its the eeprom. Do you know if its possible to recover when it's not even reading any inserted devices?

Comment: I don't see how, no;  I've never messed with the eeprom, if the only way to flash that is from a running system it sounds like you are out of luck :(